# On apk update, add more images to the app's folder

Tags: android, android-file

I would like to add more images to my app's folder when some tries to update my app. Problem here is i don't understand how to add more images to my app as my understanding is that the asset folders cannot be modified once installed am i right?

So lets say initially i've already include 10 images in the asset folder. Some one installed it and they have the 10 images, then subsequent update, there are 10 new images(20 in total). When someone tried to update that, will they get 20 images?

Thanks.

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: every time when you update your APK only fresh static contents like assets,drawable are considered. Old data is get removed which will updated with your new updated data.

Comment: It's not possible. better to add images from your server.